# Map set of points which values represent a radius to a circle with radius R

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have a set of data points that represent a radius. My threshold radius is R. If my data points have a radius < R or a radius > R, I would like to show it visually with Matlab.

I have plotted the circle successfully (using the equation of the circle), but my data points are plotted outside the circle even though their values are less than R. I think I am not properly mapping the data points.

I am doing the following:

```
%% Circle %%
% Radius = 1;
tx = linspace(-1,1,100);  %% X-data
ty = sqrt(1-tx.^2);      %% Y-data
ty2 = -ty;                %% (-)Y-data
%% Data Points %%
list_radius =[0.5870 0.2077 0.3012 0.4709 1.1524 6.7545 1.5581 1.8074];
%% PLOT %%
plot(tx,ty,':r',tx,ty2,':r')
hold on 
plot(list_radius)
hold off
```

I was expecting to see the points with list_radius < 1 inside the circle and the points with list_radius > 1 outside the circle. 
Thanks for your help!

Comment: It is not clear what you're trying to plot: if you call `plot` with one parameter (an array) the function consider it as the set of ordinate and assume the abscissa be the integers `1:length of the array`., This is way all your `list_radius` points are outside the circle. You have to define the `x` coordinates of the point of `list_radius`.

Comment: Yeah. And if you have "radius" values, those don't sound like they are either `x` or `y` coordinates in cartesian space, the way `tx`, `ty`, and `ty2` are. You need to either map those "radius" values to (x,y) points, or work in polar coordinates, or... something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you plot circles generating `x` and `y` points for a circle with

x = R·cos(Θ)

y = R·sin(Θ)

where Theta is a vector from 0 to 2*pi and R is your desired radius. Using this equation you don't have to generate a vector `ty2` and you can plot your circle with one plot command.

```
R = 1;
theta = linspace(0,2*pi,1000);

tx = R*cos(theta);
ty = R*sin(theta);

list_radius =[0.5870 0.2077 0.3012 0.4709 1.1524 6.7545 1.5581 1.8074];

plot(tx,ty,':r');
hold on;
plot(list_radius,zeros(1,numel(list_radius)),'*');
axis equal
```

With this snippet I assumed your `list_radius` points lie on the x-axis.